Не могу установить pynacl на Termux
При установке pip install pynacl, получаю ошибку:
File "", line 160, in run                       File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call                      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)              subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-jd6596wc/pynacl_618d0f94d04a4bf3b0dd3358a142750d/src/libsodium/configure', '--disable-shared', '--enable-static', '--disable-debug', '--disable-dependency-tracking', '--with-pic', '--prefix', '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-jd6596wc/pynacl_618d0f94d04a4bf3b0dd3358a142750d/build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311']' returned non-zero exit status 1.                                                    [end of output]                                                                                             note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.                            ERROR: Failed building wheel for pynacl               Failed to build pynacl                                  ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pynacl)

У меня тоже возникала такая ошибка. Итак, пара уточнений:
Termux --> 0.118.0 
python --> 3.11.2 (установлена кастомная версия с
помощью pyenv) 
pip --> 24.3.1 
архитектура процессора --> aarch64
android --> 13 
root --> отсутствует

Что я делал:
pkg update
pkg upgrade
pkg install libsodium
SODIUM_INSTALL=system pip install pynacl

Как видим - успешно!


это точно ответ?

У человека не устанавливался pynacl на termux. У меня тоже он не устанавливался. Я видел, что на подобный вопрос уже был дан ответ, однако мне он не помог  поэтому я предоставил свой вариант действий, которые, как видите - мне помогли. Поэтому я считаю это ответом, так как проблема в итоге решена‍♂️
